postgreSQL server 13.13 version , setting the log_statement (none,ddl,mod) parameter not effect the log file
We are using postgreSQL server 13.13 version , setting the log_statement (none,ddl,mod,all) parameter does not effect the log file output.
Setting log_statement = none and restart server
Upgrading from postgreSQL 13.13 to 13.16 version
also does not affect outputs in $PGDATA/log/postgresql-xxx.log files
The postgresql 13.16 server works in such a way that it is as if log_statement is set to all, but it is set to none. All of logs writes into $PGDATA/log/postgresql-xxx.log file.
